# Different settings for Dev, AdHoc, and App Store builds

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I'd like to have different names for my development, adhoc, and App store releases.

For now, I can only have different settings for Dev and AdHoc/AppStore builds using [this Chris Miles' blog post](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/04/ios-dev-beta-production-builds.html).

But since Adhoc & App Store builds both use the `Archive` settings, I couldn't find a way to differentiate them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is set up two targets, one for adhoc and one for app store.  Then you can customize the build settings for each in the Build Settings section.

Comment: Well, this produces a lot of settings duplication, but it works ;) Thanks!